# How to refresh applied fonts?

Tags: scripting, objects, text-object

I'm creating a font ad-hoc and modifying It as I need time to time..

Any way to reload the font file linked to the *.blend file so all text objects are immediately refreshed?

Now I need to reload the font file for every text object at every modification...

Is there maybe a way to apply the font to a material via nodes? (or something like [maybe a script?])

[image: font need a refresh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the interface there is currently no way to replace the file for an existing font *(ideally this would be supported)*,
however from Python you can do this.

eg, run this script:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.object.data.font.filepath = '//some_font.ttf'
```

However in 2.76 there is a bug where this won't update immediately ([just fixed](https://developer.blender.org/rB40b748d40f7efddbd07f35081a3264215025ffb8)).

So you have to do...

```
import bpy
bpy.context.object.data.font.filepath = '//some_font.ttf'
bpy.context.object.data.update_tag()
```

You could set the file-path to its self to force reloading too.

Comment: It works! but I'm missing something basic... how to apply this to all the selected text objects and not only the active one?

Comment: ock! found out how to do that and discovered an alternative solution! ^_^ thanks for your precious work ideasman!!!!!!

Comment: @FrancescoYoshiGobbo, could you post your solution as an answer? (so anyone who finds this question can use it).

Answer (score 1):

Found out an alternative solution:

Will perform this task performing a selection of all the 'font type' objects by

1. text object selection <kbd>RMB</kbd>
2. select grouped <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>: Type <kbd>T</kbd>
3. change the font of the only active element
4. make links <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>: Fonts <kbd>F</kbd>

This update applies to all the selected text objects!